# Preventing move semantics during pattern matching

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, move-semantics

I have a silly example here, just to demonstrate an issue I'm running into with another library and pattern matching.

```
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: i32,
    choice: Choices
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Choices {
    Good,
    Neutral,
    Evil
}

fn find(p: Person) {
    match (p.choice, p.age) {
        (Choices::Good, a) if a < 80 => {
            announce(p);
        }
        (_, a) if a >= 80 => {
            println!("You're too old to care.");
        }
        _ => {
            println!("You're not very nice!")
        }
    }
}

fn announce(p: Person) {
    println!("Your name is {}. You are {:?}.", p.name, p.choice);
}

fn main() {
    let p = Person {
                name: "Bob".to_string(),
                age: 20,
                choice: Choices::Good
            };
    find(p);
}
```

Now the issue seems to be that during pattern matching, move semantics will kick in and take ownership over the inner struct (Thing) in my Person.

When I go to move the person on to the next method, I can't because it's been partially moved.

```
Compiling match v0.1.0 (file:///home/jocull/Documents/Projects/Rust/learn/match)
src/main.rs:17:13: 17:14 error: use of partially moved value: `p`
src/main.rs:17          announce(p);
                                 ^
src/main.rs:15:9: 15:17 note: `p.choice` moved here because it has type `Choices`, which is non-copyable
src/main.rs:15  match (p.choice, p.age) {
                       ^~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `match`.
```

My gut says I need to get Rust to stop moving the value by using a reference or borrow of some kind. In this case I **could** change my method signature to borrow, but with some libraries you aren't always able to do that. (I am trying to deal with [hyper](https://crates.io/crates/hyper) in this case...)

Is there a way to get the `match` to use references during matching instead of moving the values? Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Why?

When you make the tuple

```
(p.choice, p.age)
```

you `memcpy` both `p.choice` and `p.age` from your `Person`.

It's OK to do this for `p.age` because it's a `Copy` type - you can continue using the old value after `memcpy`ing from it.

`p.choices` is of type `Choices` which is **not** `Copy`. This means that the `memcpy` is treated as a "move", so the old value is not usable. This means `p` is in an invalid state, so you can't call `announce` on it.

#### Solution #1

Since `Choices` is a trivial `enum`, you can just `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]`. This means that you are allowed to continue using the old `p.choices`.

If you can only safely make `Choices` `Clone`, then you'd have to `clone` it in the `match` instead.

#### Solution #2

You can take `p.choices` by *reference*:

```
match (&p.choice, p.age) {
    (&Choices::Good, a) if a < 80 => {
        announce(p);
    }
    ...
}
```

This only works because `&Choices::Good` is an exact match so the borrow can be relinquished. If you had instead

```
match (&p.choice, p.age) {
    (&x, a) if a < 80 => {
        announce(p);
    }
    ...
}
```

the borrow would still be active and so the move when calling `announce(p)` would fail - the move would invalidate an active borrowed variable.

#### Notes

You're doing an awful lot of moving here - passing a few references is a lot more flexible! There's no reason for `announce` to *consume* a `Person` - it just needs to look at it for a bit. Taking by value when you could take a reference is only advisable for small `Copy` types.

Note that having `announce` take a reference means that the `match` is allowed to also be holding on to references inside `p`, which makes it more widely applicable.

`to_string` is mostly for use for non-string objects. `into` and `to_owned` are faster and `into` is also a lot shorter.

```
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: i32,
    choice: Choices
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
enum Choices {
    Good,
    Neutral,
    Evil
}

fn find(p: &Person) {
    match (p.choice, p.age) {
        (Choices::Good, a) if a < 80 => {
            announce(p);
        }
        (_, a) if a >= 80 => {
            println!("You're too old to care.");
        }
        _ => {
            println!("You're not very nice!")
        }
    }
}

fn announce(p: &Person) {
    println!("Your name is {}. You are {:?}.", p.name, p.choice);
}

fn main() {
    let p = Person {
        name: "Bob".into(),
        age: 20,
        choice: Choices::Good
    };

    find(&p);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining in so much length :)

Comment: In hyper (the mentioned library) this was the issue with enums being non-copy. The borrow trick here is a good solution when the underlying libraries leave out things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I try again with the new code change :)

In your current code, if you use borrowing instead of moving in the match it works.

`p.age` doesn't need that only because it's a primitive type and primitive types implement the [`Copy` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html#copy-types)

But Choices do not implement the copy trait and so they are moved in the match. Which causes them to not be available when you call `announce()`

```rust
match (&p.choice, p.age) {
        (&Choices::Good, a) if a < 80 => {
            announce(p);
        }
        ...
}
```

It get rids of the error about partial move. I guess it is because you moved choice in the match. But choice is a part of Person so it's partially moved.

**I have not enough knowledge of Rust to truly explain why it works, so if you can add something useful, please do**

Comment: I modified my original sample some to make it clearer about non-copy items (the enum in the new example). I was trying to better understand how pattern matching takes ownership rather than modifying the underlying code. Some of it is library code I won't have access to change.

Comment: @jocull I changed my answer for your update, I hope it's helpful