# Why is this struct not moved after pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, rust, move

Based on [Preventing move semantics during pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562985/preventing-move-semantics-during-pattern-matching), my understanding is when I do a `match` on a struct, if not using a reference to do the match, the struct will be moved since it is not a primitive type. To test this, I implemented the following:

```
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

let origin = Point { x: 0, y: 0 };

match origin {
    Point { x: x1, y: y1 } => println!("({},{})", x1, y1),
}

// to check if the origin has been moved, and it seems not, why ?? 
match origin {
    Point { x: x1, y: y1 } => println!("({},{})", x1, y1),
}
```

The output is `(0,0) (0,0)`, which means the original struct is still there. Shouldn't it have been moved after the first `match`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What matters is not the type of the value being matched, but rather the type of each value being bound on each match arm.

In your struct `Point`, the fields `x` and `y` are of type `i32`. This type implements `Copy`, so Rust will copy values of this type instead of moving them – this means that the original value is still considered valid. Since all the values being bound on the match arm implement `Copy`, it's not necessary to invalidate `origin`. Field access works similarly: `origin.x` doesn't invalidate `origin` when `origin.x` implements `Copy`!

Now, if the fields were of a type that doesn't implement `Copy` (say, `String`), then that's a different story. Rust is forced to move each `String` from the field to the binding in the match arm. As a result, the fields in `origin` are invalidated. Since we can't use a value with invalidated fields, then the whole struct is invalidated as well.

Let's spice things up a little. Consider the following code:

```
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: String,
}

let origin = Point { x: 0, y: "zero".to_string() };

match origin {
    Point { x: x1, y: _ } => println!("({},...)", x1),
}

match origin {
    Point { x: x1, y: _ } => println!("({},...)", x1),
}

match origin {
    Point { x: _, y: y1 } => println!("(...,{})", y1),
}

match origin {
    Point { x: _, y: y1 } => println!("(...,{})", y1),
}
```

Here, we're using the placeholder pattern (`_`) to say we're not interested in the value of a certain field. We could also use a wildcard pattern (`..`, as in `Point { x: x1, .. }`) to ignore all the fields that are not named in the struct pattern. In either case, it has the effect of **not moving the ignored field(s)**.

In the first two matches, we only bind the `x` field, which is of type `i32`. Since `i32` implements `Copy`, `origin` is not invalidated, even though neither `origin` nor `origin.y` are copyable (`origin.y` just stays where it is).

In the third match, we only bind the `y` field, which is of type `String`. Since `String` doesn't implement `Copy`, `origin.y` is moved into `y1`, so `origin` is invalidated. This causes compiler errors on the fourth match, as it tries to use `origin` after it has been invalidated:

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `origin`
  --> <anon>:21:11
   |
18 |         Point { x: _, y: y1 } => println!("(...,{})", y1),
   |                          -- value moved here
...
21 |     match origin {
   |           ^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `origin.y` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `origin.y`
  --> <anon>:22:26
   |
18 |         Point { x: _, y: y1 } => println!("(...,{})", y1),
   |                          -- value moved here
...
22 |         Point { x: _, y: y1 } => println!("(...,{})", y1),
   |                          ^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `origin.y` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```